# Get the Tray Icon to bounce in Mac

Tags: java, macos, notifications, trayicon

I am developing an application that needs to display messages to the user on Mac. The messages always have a yes and no option for the user, and I can display these, but right now, I am forcing something to show up over whatever the user has open, and I would really like to make the doc icon bounce. Better yet, I would like to integrate the icon that I have in the menubar at the top of the screen.

Is there some way to easily make the dock icon bounce in Java? The only way that I found to work without implementing other applications involves using the `java.awt.displayMessage()` method to show a message.

Comment: I'd guess any code to do this will require some native mac code. I don't know how to make this happen but your question is certainly interesting.

Comment: I've looked at that post, and I cannot use that because I am using Java 6, and I have to use 64-bit libraries. I'm not sure which one exactly, but one of the methods being used comes from a 32-bit library that I could not find the 64-bit version of anywhere. I realize that I also neglected to mention that I am developing in Netbeans 7.

Comment: The linked question was written using Java 6 (the API call is a Java 6 API method)

Comment: I apologize for not putting this earlier, as I forgot that the part of my application that would have connected to this was the part without the library, not this part exactly. I was forced to use a slightly different Application class, I believe it is different anyway because the requestUserAttention() method takes an int not a boolean, and it isn't actually making the app bounce. I have focus on other apps while I call it and it still doesn't work. And it definitely says Java 1.7 in the post.

Comment: com.apple.eawt.Application is "Apple" API which is part of Apples Java RT since (I believe) 1.4, which I was surprised to find in the Java 7 API, hence the comment. As to the bit depthness, that is dependent on the JRE and not the compiled code. As stated in the previous question, the example was running at Java 64. When I (finally) get home, I will compile and test it on my old mini running Java 6

Comment: @BobbyD17 I modified the linked example (as it was using multi catch statement), compiled it using Java 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 and it ran fine.  I then took the same compiled code an ran it on Java 1.7.0_06 on Mac OS 10.8.4 without issue

Comment: @BobbyD17 I also run it another machine using 10.7.5 and Java 1.7.0_15 and it worked fine

Comment: I got it to work. It seems that I had another class named Application that worked very similarly to this one, but must have been modified for some reason. I was able to get this to work. Thank you guys. How do I close this question without deleting it so that if other people find it, they can redirect to the other one?